# gulp silently failing - no errors printed to console

Tags: gulp

My gulp file is not emitting any errors on either standard gulp methods like gulp.src() with non existant paths nor are stream errors being called by their handler.  I've included a simple file that silently fails, printing only the starting.. and finished.. default messages.

```
var //
  gulp      = require( "gulp" ),
  gulpUtil  = require( "gulp-util" ),
  sass      = require( "gulp-ruby-sass");


 gulp.task( "default", function() {
  gulp.src( "path-that-does-not-exist.scss" )
  .pipe( sass() )
  .on( "error", function( err ) {
    console.log( "this should print" );
  })
  .pipe( gulp.dest( "./client-side/public/compiled" ) );
 });
```

Comment: If the file does not exist, then the stream is simply not processed.  I'm not sure what you expect to happen here.

Comment: Presumably you'd want a way to detect whether the path exists, would you not? If not on the "error" event, then some other event.

Comment: You can put a flag on top the task, e.g. anyData = false; then set it to true within the chain, then look in .on('end', function() { }) whether it has been set. If not, then raise an error. It's a bit hacky, and you might just want to check whether the file exists using fs :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Okay, so Gulp is working "correctly." But what I'm hearing in your question is that it would be nice if Gulp could just tell you if a file doesn't exist.

I use [gulp-expect-file](https://github.com/kotas/gulp-expect-file) as such

```
var coffee = require('gulp-coffee');
var expect = require('gulp-expect-file');

gulp.task('mytask', function() {
  var files = ['idontexist.html'];

  return gulp.src(files)
    .pipe(expect(files))
    .pipe(coffee());
});
```

Now you'll see this in the terminal:

[image: example output]

Comment: Notice that it won't prevent gulp from going on, so keep a look at the console !

Answer (score 4):

If the path does not exist, gulp.src successfully pushes exactly nothing through the pipe, the sass and dest tasks successfully are never called, and with that, gulp.src's stream ends, signaling the default task is complete, and gulp exits.  It has done exactly what you've told it to.  :D

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @adamjgrant use [gulp-expect-file](https://github.com/kotas/gulp-expect-file).

```
var expect = require('gulp-expect-file'),
    gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('task', function() {
    var files = ['src/js/*.js'];
    gulp
        .src(files)
        .pipe(expect(files));
});
```

PS: Grunt.js handles this with `nonull:true`

```
lint: {
    src: ['gruntfile.js', 'gulpfile.js'],
    nonull: true
}
```