# How to get gulp to error on missing file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I've got gulpfile.js set up like this:

```
var scripts = [
    'bower_components/timezone-js/src/date.js',                            
    'bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js',                               
    'bower_components/jquery-migrate/jquery-migrate.js',                   
    'bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js',              
    'bower_components/jqueryui-touch-punch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js',  
    ...
];

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src(scripts, {base: '.'})
        .pipe(plumber(plumberOptions))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({
            loadMaps: false,
            debug: debug,
        }))
        ...
```

i.e., all my script files are exact matches. No globbing.

Every now and then I mess up a file path or the author changes the directory structure. I want to be notified when this happens instead of the script silently being excluded and causing run-time errors.

Is there some way for me to make `gulp.src` report these kinds of errors?

Comment: use [gulp-expect-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-expect-file), also why not use `wiredep` to get bower_components??

Comment: @entre Hadn't heard of those, but I don't think I like them. expect-file is for testing which files are on the pipe after they've already been put on the pipe; seems redundant. An option to or replacement for .src would be preferable (perhaps I'll write one), and wiredep I *really* don't like. I don't like making my bower deps public, I don't want to include the files separately, I don't like HTML comment placeholders, and I'm not using HTML source files.

Comment: actually, using gulp-expect-file is not too bad: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25702304

Comment: @rve Oh..don't know why I didn't think to use it like that. That would have been perfect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [gulp-expect-file](https://github.com/kotas/gulp-expect-file) as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25702304/65387).

```
var coffee = require('gulp-coffee');
var expect = require('gulp-expect-file');

gulp.task('mytask', function() {
  var files = ['idontexist.html'];

  return gulp.src(files)
    .pipe(expect(files))
    .pipe(coffee());
});
```

(Thanks [rve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30265677/how-to-get-gulp-to-error-on-missing-file/30386037#comment56453053_30265677))

Answer (score 0):

`gulp.src` is actually just an alias to `vinyl-fs.src` which looks like this:

```
function src(glob, opt) {
  opt = opt || {};
  var pass = through.obj();

  if (!isValidGlob(glob)) {
    throw new Error('Invalid glob argument: ' + glob);
  }
  // return dead stream if empty array
  if (Array.isArray(glob) && glob.length === 0) {
    process.nextTick(pass.end.bind(pass));
    return pass;
  }

  var options = defaults(opt, {
    read: true,
    buffer: true
  });

  var globStream = gs.create(glob, options);

  // when people write to use just pass it through
  var outputStream = globStream
    .pipe(through.obj(createFile))
    .pipe(getStats(options));

  if (options.read !== false) {
    outputStream = outputStream
      .pipe(getContents(options));
  }

  return outputStream.pipe(pass);
}
```

It in turn uses [glob-stream](https://github.com/wearefractal/glob-stream) which uses [glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob). You can probably bypass most of that and use [through2](https://github.com/rvagg/through2) directly to create a pipe from the array files. I haven't figured out how to do this yet.